# Is clang/gcc or MSVC correct in this constexpr/static_assert case?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

I have the following [code](https://www.godbolt.org/z/3E2AOZ) , MSVC and clang/gcc disagree, MSVC accepts it.
I presume MSFT is wrong(godbolt does not have newest compiler, but I do and Intellisense is also complaining while compiler compiles it even with permissive-).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
void bla() {
  constexpr int64_t val1 = 1;
  constexpr int64_t val2 = val1 - 1;
  constexpr tuple<int64_t> tup1(val1);
  constexpr tuple<int64_t> tup2(val2);
  const double d1 = std::get<0>(tup1);
  const double d2 = std::get<0>(tup2);
  static_assert(d1 != d2);
}
```

note: this is mostly theoretical question, I can easily make those variables constexpr.

Comment: What do you mean by "accepts it"? Does the static assert not fire?

Comment: I think you mean `(d1 != d2)`. Seems like msvc bug, clang/gcc say `d1` and `d2` need to be constexpr, which is true.

Comment: You should really add the errors from the compilers.

Comment: @bolov there is the link in question to godbolt

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant compiles it, will update the Q

Comment: @cigien yeah, messed up while reducing example

Comment: Also, there's a conformance viewer in godbolt that makes it easier to see the comparisons.

Comment: @NicolBolas I messed up the example when reducing it, now it should be fine

Comment: your question should be self sufficient. The godbolt link is nice, but we shouldn't go to another site just to see what the error is.

Comment: @cigen I agree it is a duplicate, thank you. It looks MSVC is just buggy(or advanced since I consider this useful).